# Incorrect output, simple strings exercise - C

Tags: c, string, printing

I am trying to write a function that gets a string of letters, either capital letters or small letters, and prints 2 other strings, one with only the capitals, and one only with the small letters. for example:

```
input: AaBbCcDD

Output: Capital string is ABCDD, non capital is abc
```

My code is not working correctly, it seems to skip over the last letter. To test it, I wrote the following code:

```
int length;
printf("Please enter length of string\n");
scanf("%d",&length);
string=create_string(length);
scan_string(string,length);
printf("The string entered is: \n");
print_string(string,length);
```

Where create_string is:

```
char* create_string(int size)
{
    char* string;
    string=(char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    return string;
}
```

Scan string is:

```
void scan_string(char* string, int size)
{
    int i;
    printf("Please enter %d characters\n",size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        scanf("%c",string+i);
}
```

And print string is

```
void print_string(char* string,int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf("%c ",*(string+i));
}
```

When I try even just to print the string I entered, this is what I get, after I input `aaAAB`

The output is `a a A A`.

it skipped over the B.

Comment: What do you input for string length?

Comment: I input 5 in said example.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to cast the return type of malloc and you shouldn't because if you get it wrong the compiler won't necessarily warn you about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `scanf` that reads  characters using `%c`: it follows the `scanf` that reads the length using `%d`, which leaves an extra `'\n'` character in the buffer *before* the first character that you get.

If you modify the output to put quotes around your characters, you would actually see the `\n`:

```
void print_string(char* string,int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf("'%c' ",*(string+i));
}
```

This prints

```
'
' 'a' 'a' 'A' 'A'
```

([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/jU8fsH))

Comment: I see...Would it be better if I used getch instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your first scanf to read '\n' as below. This will read the extra '\n'

scanf("%d\n", &length);

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is unnecessarily elaborated. To read a string the function `fget()` with parameter `stdin` is a simpler choice.
For example, I wuold not ask to the user for the length of the string.
Perhaps it is better to use a buffer with fixed length, and to restrit the user to enter a string with the length less than which you have been previously stipulated.

```
  #define MAXLEN 1000
  char buffer[MAXLEN] = "";
  fgets(buffer, MAXLEN, stdin);
```

If the user attempts to enter a string with more than MAXLEN characters, it would be necessary to handle the end-of-line in some way, but I think this is out of topic.
So, in general, let us suppose that MAXLEN is large enough such that buffer contains the `\n` mark.

Now, a call to your function `print_string()` can be done.

However, it would be better to do this:

```
  printf("%s", buffer);
```

I think that you probably need to take in account the C convention for strings: a string is a char array whose last element is marked with the character `'\0'` (null character, having always code 0).

Even if you want to insist in your approach, I think that `scanf()` is a bad choice to read individual characters. it is more easy to use `getchar()`, instead.

By using `scanf()` you have to broke your brain figurating out all the stuff around the behaviour of `scanf()`, or how to handle the read of characters, and so on.

However, `getchar()` reads one char at a time, and that's (almost) all. (Actually, the console commonly not returns the control to the user until an end-of-line `\n` has been read).

```
  string[i] = getchar();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the `scanf` does not eat the `"\n"`. Hence there is still one '`\n'` remaining at your first input. This will be counted at the next scanf.
Try to put an additional `getchar()` right after your first `scanf`.

```
printf("Please enter length of string\n");
scanf("%d",&length);

getchar(); // remove '\n'

string=create_string(length);
```